# Hyper-V 2012 and P2000 SAS SAN

Tags: hyper-v, storage, sas

Hi I am having major problems setting up a Hyper-V 2012 cluster on a P2000 SAS SAN.

Running System Center VMM 2012 SP1 I am unable to see any storage to create my cluster. Has anyone had experienced anything similar? Under fabric and storage I can't add the P2000, all I can do is use storage spaces in server manager to create a storage pool and virtual disk. This allows me to create a file share which I can add to VMM but I still can't see any disk to create a cluster. I am just about at the point where I want to tear my hair out wipe the servers and stick VMware on them because I know it works as I have set several systems up like this in the past.

The Hyper-V servers can see the storage and in server manager on my management machine it seems to know both servers can see the same disk. VMM is running on the same machine and it can't see any disk.

Help.....
Thanks
Mike

Comment: What P2000 model is this exactly? You might be needing a [proxy driver for SMI-S support](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/storage/smis-matrix.html) (as SMI-S is the only interface SCVMM would talk to your storage over).

Comment: Are you running Firmware TS240P004? VMM requires SMI-S version 1.5 Please let us know what the outcome is as we intend to use the same solution SAS-based.

Answer (score 1):

We were having a similar problem with our P2000 and Windows Server 2012.  After talking with HP we were informed that they did not currently have any drivers available for the P2000 and Window Server 2012 and that they did not currently have any Storage certified for Windows Server 2012.

We were able to create the cluster using the Failover Cluster Manager with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to create a cluster and see any disks capable of shared storage is to remove the P2000 from the Hyper-V hosts, connect is to a third server, create an ISCSI target and present this to the hosts. This passes the cluster validation test, lets me create a cluster and a cluster shared volume. Though I can't do anything with sotrage spaces - I think this is because storage spaces requires direct access to the disks and the P2000 presents a VDisk to Windows.

This seems really messy to me and it involves an extra level of abstraction that complicates the design and I have had several volume corruptions when I tested disconnecting the ISCSI targets and reconnecting them. In fact when I formated the volume as Refs I had two unrecoverable corruptions and had to reformat the volume.

I'm not happy to put this in to production as you can guess at this stage. but am running out of options. I may need to go to the client and suggest we go VMWare, we will loose some of the nice features of Hyper-V but at least I will be 100% confident it will work.

Comment: Model number for the P2000 G3 is BV917A. Firmware version is TS240P003. I have a case open with HP at the moment. Gregory - how is your system connected - is is SAS?